# HMM and non categorical values of emmision (MATLAB)

Tags: hmm

I read through a tutorial on MATLAB website on [HMM](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com#f10382). It is not easy to digest so I had to look for other sources and found a good explanation on [Wikipedia (HMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model). Everything is more understandable but there are still a couple of things I find unclear.

Please correct me if I ma wrong, [in the example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model):

- the states are X = {1, 2} (red, green)
- probability that: system stays in red = 0.9, moves from red to green = 0.1, stays in green = 0.95, moves from green to red = 0.05. I understand rows and columns of TRANS correspond to state before and after transition
- because of two states, transition matrix T is 2x2
- Y = {1,2,3,4,5,6} - observations
- emission [in the example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com#f10382) is categorical
- probability distribution is determined in EMIS matrix
- the matrix EMIS is 2x6 due to 2 states and 6 different observations per state; probability of emission depends on a state and can be different in each state: in red, probability of each observation Y = {1,2,3, ..., 6} is equal; in green probability is weighted towards 1.

[Wikipedia](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com#f10382) also explains that probability that we observe a particular output doesn't have to be categorical. In the example [on MATLAB website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) I understand that emission is categorical. How can I chnage it to apply continuous probability distribution so that I would have similar outputs? I am thinking of Guassian distr. or Guassian Mixture distr. to increase probability of Y = 1.

Thanks

Comment: I mean that observed variable and its emission is discrete with possible categories

Comment: Observe answer by  MathWorks Support Team [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100850-how-can-i-use-continuous-sequence-values-with-hmmestimate-in-the-statistics-toolbox-7-1-r2009a). apparently "The ability to do hidden Markov model estimation for continuous-valued emissions is not available in the Statistics Toolbox 7.1 (R2009a)."

Comment: They do suggest [this toolbox](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm.html) instead.

Comment: @havakok Thanks for the answer and link to another toolbox. I guess they have not changed much since 2012. We currently use MATLAB 2015 SP1 with Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox Version 10.0 (R2015aSP1).

Comment: I am sorry I could not help any further. I could not find any other reference to any other toolkit. Maybe the correct procedure is posting to whoever is releasing this toolbox?